# Text on path animation in After Effects without the smooth turn on the corner

Tags: animation, video, after-effects

When animating text around a rectangle mask in After Effects, the letters follow the path and just smoothly turn around the corner. I, however, want the letters to 'skip' the corner and just switch from vertical to horizontal line. See example: https://d2w9rnfcy7mm78.cloudfront.net/2420161/original_71f06f6283876df1f130b219750f212b.gif?1531411776?bc=1

How do I do that?

(Perhaps I should use something other than After Effects?)

Answer (score 0):

They don't smoothly turn around the corner -- except you have a rounded rectangle.

[image: difference between rounded and straight rectangle]

On a straight corner rectangle, they "jump".

I think, the example you are showing uses **several different paths** (there is a gap which can not be explained by one path). Those different paths are just nicely synced animated.